# Visual Basic Delete Algorithm Doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, file-io

This is a rehash of a previous question that went unanswered.

I have a Record and a file with a collection of records in. I want to delete a record from that file. This algorithm should take the record to be deleted from the file, mark the record for deletion, resave the record to the file and then copy all of the records APART from the record marked for deletion into a new temp file that becomes the main file.

What goes wrong: for some reason the algorithm still copies the record marked for deletion except without the correct fields. It turns the fields blank but still sticks it in the new file for some reason.

I will single-step through the code and watch the code only run the `FilePut` method three times when there are four records (showing that only three of four records are copied to the new file and one is left to be deleted as expected) but when the file is loaded into a report it still contains a blank record. This makes no sense and nobody has been able to solve my problem!

```
Dim n As Integer = 1
Dim TempDir As String = CurDir() & "\Temp.dat"
RecordNumber = Trim(Val(Mid(lstResultReport.Text, 1, 3)))
FileGet(4, ResultRecord, RecordNumber)

ResultRecord.TournamentName = "DELETE"
FilePut(4, ResultRecord, RecordNumber)
FileClose(4)
FileOpen(4, ResultsFilePath, OpenMode.Random, , , Len(ResultRecord))
FileOpen(5, TempDir, OpenMode.Random, , , Len(ResultRecord))

For n = 1 To LOF(4) / Len(ResultRecord)
    FileGet(4, ResultRecord, n)
    If Trim(ResultRecord.TournamentName) <> "DELETE" Then
        FilePut(5, ResultRecord, n)
    End If
Next
FileClose(4) 
FileClose(5)


Kill(ResultsFilePath)
FileCopy(TempDir, ResultsFilePath)
Kill(TempDir)
FileOpen(4, ResultsFilePath, OpenMode.Random, , , Len(ResultRecord))
```

**UPDATE** Interestingly, the algorithm works when I go to delete the last record in the file.

Comment: Uhm... Long live VB6.  *sigh*  This is 2015, yo.

Comment: My crystal ball says that you are overwriting an existing file.  But it still has an old record that you did not overwrite.  You'll have to delete Temp.dat first.

Comment: Do you mean when I open/create the temp.dat file? i.e  'Dim TempDir As String = CurDir() & "\Temp.dat"' and then 'FileOpen(5, TempDir, OpenMode.Random, , , Len(ResultRecord))? '

Because I tried that but it didn't solve my problem

Comment: @Dan-o This is VB.NET. Surprisingly many people here use VB.NET and tag their questions with VB6.

Comment: see my answer, and no, your code does NOT work on the last record. the last record is simple not written ....

Comment: Sorry, both times I placed this as VB.Net in tags (including this time) I was told that it was not.NET. Last time I posted this question I believe I was downvoted for the code not being VB.NET. I thought this was VB.NET but you know when everyone ( is telling you otherwise you doubt yourself.

Comment: I see that it's vb.net.  Its just the long lost bastard child of VB6 that makes you wish the '90s never happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I mean:

```
dim newPosition as integer ' !!!
newPosition = 1            ' !!!
For n = 1 To LOF(4) / Len(ResultRecord)
    FileGet(4, ResultRecord, n)
    If Trim(ResultRecord.TournamentName) <> "DELETE" Then
        FilePut(5, ResultRecord, newPostion)
        newPostion = newPosition + 1 ' !!!
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I got ya sorry took me ages but I logged out. This is great, such a silly error on my behalf, something that is easy to overlook I guess since those that I showed couldn't work it out either! THANKS